# What is the second derivative of the absolute function $\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question

I calculated the derivative of $\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|$ in the same way that I would do with $ \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ in order to study the function.

But when I verified on wolfram, I noticed it is all wrong. Wolfram uses the chain rule [as you can see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=first%20derivative%20of%20%7C%5Cfrac%7Bx%2B1%7D%7Bx%2B2%7D%5Cright%7C%5C).

I don't get it. The only rule I've been taught as far as absolute function derivatives are concerned, is $|x|' = \frac{x}{|x|}$. Does a similar rule apply for $f(x)$? And why does wolfram uses chain rule?

---

**Edit**

I calculated the derivatives as there is no absolute and then, at the result, I applied the absolute.

My answers are $|(\frac{x+1}{x+2})|' = |(\frac{x+1}{x+2})'| = \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$ and $|(\frac{x+1}{x+2})|'' = |(\frac{x+1}{x+2})''| = \frac{2}{\left(x+2\right)^3}$

Wolfram's answer is

$\left(\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|\right)'\:=\frac{\left|x+2\right|\left(x+1\right)}{\left|x+1\right|\left(x+2\right)^3}$

---

Comment: What answer did you get? It's easier to answer "why use the chain rule" if we can point out exactly where you went wrong.

Comment: We can't guess what you did, so we can't tell where "it is all wrong".

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I deal with absolute functions:

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)^{2}}\\
\\
\frac{d}{dx} \left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|&=\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)^{2}}}\cdot 2 \left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^{2}}\\
&=\frac{x+1}{\left(x+2\right)^{3}\cdot\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|}
\end{align}
$$

Notice the chain rule when I differentiate the square root

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: The term $\left(\frac{1}{x+2}\right)^{2}$ would be better writen as $\frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^{2}}$ – it's the denominator which gets squared in differentating a ratio. The numerator reduces to $1$ and $1$ squared equals $1$, so the equality holds whith $1^2$, but there's no reason to introduce squaring to numerator.

Comment: @CiaPan that is spot on! Edited it, thanks.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja goodness, thank you so much for that original approach, it will be really useful to me!! :))

Comment: @A-levelStudent ur welcome mate

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

As

$$\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|=\pm\frac{x+1}{x+2},$$

it is legitimate to take the derivative of the fraction without the absolute value.

Instead of an absolute value, you will use a piecewise definition where the sign is adjusted in every interval, and the derivatives naturally follow.

Comment: Altough it seems right to me, I think it comes in contrast with the result Wolfram suggested i.e $\left(\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|\right)'\:=\frac{\left|x+2\right|\left(x+1\right)}{\left|x+1\right|\left(x+2\right)^3}$

Comment: @Euler: how can you tell that these answers differ ?

Comment: I guess I do not understand the part where you say "Then you adjust the sign to match the absolute value (there are three intervals to consider)." We have $\left(-\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)'\:=-\frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$ and $\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)' =\frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$ . Both cases are different from the previous answer.

Comment: @Euler: beware that $|f|'=|f'|$ is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Euler: I don't think that you learnt from this case. :-(

Comment: Although I highly appreciate you, because your answers have helped me many times, to be honest I don't understand this one. You said: "It is legitimate to take the derivative w/o the absolute value" i.e: $ \left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)' = \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$. Next, you write to adjust the sign to math the absolute value and that there are three intervals to consider. I guess these are $(-\infty,-2) \bigcup (-2,-1) \bigcup (-1, \infty)$.  But I don't understand what to do next with those intervals. Consider what exactly?

Comment: @Euler: instantiate $\pm$ accordingly.

Comment: Ah, you mean: $(-\infty,-2): f'(x) = \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$ and $ (-2,-1): f'(x) = - \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$ and $(-1, \infty): f'(x) = \frac{1}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$. That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @Euler: yes, you get it ! I am adding a comment about this.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, using [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) we have that for $x\neq -1,-2$

$$\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|=\frac{x+1}{x+2}\cdot \frac{\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|}{\frac{x+1}{x+2}}=\frac{x+1}{x+2} \operatorname{sign}\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)$$

therefore by chain rule, since $(\operatorname{sign}(x))'=0 $ for $x\neq 0$, we obtain

$$\frac d{dx}\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|=\left(\frac d{dx}\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)\operatorname{sign}\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)=\frac1{(x+2)^2}\operatorname{sign}\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)=\frac{\left|\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right|}{(x+1)(x+2)}$$

which is an equivalent form for the derivative.

Comment: That was really nice!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye